# json to csv comma issue javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to convert the json to csv in javascript,
Below code works, but in scenario example if header `details` has values seperated by comma
`service, finance`, then value get shifted to next columns

```
  convertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','

            line += array[i][index];
        }
        console.log(str, line);
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}

  exportCSV =(tabledata) =>{
    const items  = tabledata;
    const fileTitle = "Sample";
    // Convert Object to JSON
    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
    var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObject);
    console.log(csv);
    var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';
    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, Sample Report);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", "Sample Report");
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}

<button onClick="exportCSV(tabledata)">Download as CSV</button>


const tabledata = [
  ["id", "details", "status"],
  [1, "service,finance", "Active"],
  [2, "service", "Inactive"],
  [3, "member,service,finance", "Active"]
]
```

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

CSV records containing special characters must be quoted.

Unless the special character is a `"` in which case it needs to be represented by a `""`.

**Don't try to write your own CSV generator**. The format is not as simple as it looks. Use a robust, maintained library like [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/)

```js
const exportCSV = (tabledata) => {
  var csv = Papa.unparse(tabledata);
  console.log(csv);
}

const tabledata = [
  ["id", "details", "status"],
  [1, "service,finance", "Active"],
  [2, "service", "Inactive"],
  [3, "member,service,finance", "Active"]
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="exportCSV(tabledata)">Download as CSV</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the data and replace it.

```
if ((data + '').includes(',')) {
    data = '\"' + data + '\"';
}
```